# Update Table Relationship in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to create a directory of sites, I'm new in Django. What I need is: one site can have many payment processors and one payment processors (Paypal, Payza, etc) can belong to many sites. I'm trying to create a table relationship to represents this. My models are like this:

```
# Models.py
class Sites(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class PaymentProcessors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Sites_PaymentProcessors(models.Model):
    site = models.ManyToMany(Sites)
    payment_processor = models.ManyToMany(PaymentProcessors)
```

First, I'd like to know if my models are right. If not, how can I fix it?

Second, I'm using Django Admin site to create the sites and payment processors, how can I populate automatically my `Sites_PaymentProcessors` table with the relation between `Sites` and `Payment_Processors` when I add a new Site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would slightly change the models to accomodate [`ManyToManyFields` like this:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships)

```
class Sites(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class PaymentProcessors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    sites = models.ManyToManyField('Sites', related_name='payment_processors')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now, if you want custom fields or store more information along with the relationship, you can make use of the [`through` table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

For example, if you want to associate the amount limit or something more custom:

```
class Sites(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class PaymentProcessors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    sites = models.ManyToManyField('Sites', related_name='payment_processors', through='SitePaymentProcessor')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator
class SitePaymentProcessor(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey('Site')
    payment_processors = models.ForeignKey('PaymentProcessors')
    amount_limit = models.IntegerField(default=1000,
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(100)
        ])
```

Now, again this is just an example.

Now, [registering the admin classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin) would enable you to populate data into the models via the admin interface.

To auto-populate a large dataset, I would consider using [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-for-models) rather than populating elements individually.